# C# Set property Copy to output directory to always from Nuget for PackageReference Projects

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, pack

I'm having a multi target framework Library that contains a set of xsd files. I want to pack this library as a nuget and add those xsds to the nuget. To do so I'm using the .cproj aproach and not the .nuspec file.

The actual adding of the files is no problem the only thing is that I want to be able to set the file property "copy to output directory" to "Always" when installing the Nuget.

I'm using the install.ps1 file as described here on stackoverflow many times and this actually sets the property for the files included in a .NET Framework project. But when you are adding the nuget to a .NET Core or .NET Standard project it doesn't do anything with the files. I think this is because the .NET Framework is using the package.config approach while het .NET Core and .NET Standard using the PackageReference.

my .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1;net45</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.0.11</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="XSD\V202001\Voorbeeld\Common.xsd" Pack="true">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="XSD\V202001\Voorbeeld\Specific.xsd">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="XSD/**/*.*" copyToOutput="true">
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
      <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
      <BuildAction>none</BuildAction>
      <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="tools\install.ps1">
      <PackagePath>tools\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How the nuget looks like from the package explorer:

[image: How the nuget looks like from the package explorer]

Can somebody tell me how to set the property to always for all frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is setting an additional property that actives the copyToOutput

changing this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="XSD/**/*.*" copyToOutput="true">
        <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
        <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
        <BuildAction>none</BuildAction>
        <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="XSD/**/*.*" copyToOutput="true">
        <BuildAction>none</BuildAction>
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

solved my problem.